# Receiving truncated data while reading from Serial Port

Tags: java, serial-port, buffer

I am trying to establish communication between Arduino and Android over Uart. So, while reading buffer on Android side I am not getting data in chunks.

```
 if (uartDevice != null) {
        // Loop until there is no more data in the RX buffer.
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            int read;
            while ((read = uartDevice.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
                data = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).substring(0, read);
                System.out.println(String.format("%020x", new BigInteger(1, data.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/))));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to transfer data over UART", e);
        }
```

Expected output is:
 2a3619010101001a0708403031301010011214084030313010100112140845

Instead I am receiving:

2a361a010101001a070840303130101001121408403031

8403031301010011214084030313010100112140845

3031301010011214084030313010100112140845

Comment: Why convert the bytes to a String and then back to bytes again? Your conversion to String also has an error. Your code asumes that all characters are one byte long.

Comment: `new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).substring(0, read);` would be a lot better and simpler expressed as `new String(buffer, 0, read, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`, but, as @RogerGustavsson truly says, the round-trip is quite pointless. It is also not guaranteed to be lossless, especially as you are taking zero care to use the same character set both times. Just use `byte[]`.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson I got your point that converting bytes to string and string to bytes is pointless.
 I changed my code to this while
((read = uartDevice.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 20); If buffer is greater that 20 bytes it would go inside the loop,but this is creating delay in my code. What should I do?

Comment: It creates a delay in your code how?

Comment: @user207421 because after receiving the data in buffer, I am processing it further by checking for its trailer and header and updating my variables according to the value received in the bytes, which I didn't show here in the above code. So, unless I receive whole bytes I can't go process further.

Comment: Well that's just a bug in your code. In general you should aim to receive as much at a time as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write code that only prints the bytes that you get I would try the following:

```
if (uartDevice != null) {
    // Loop until there is no more data in the RX buffer.
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        int read;
        while ((read = uartDevice.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < read; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to transfer data over UART", e);
    }
    System.out.println();  // Adds a newline after all bytes
}
```

---

The following is a method that takes a `UartDevice` as a parameter, reads from it until the end and returns a single `byte` array with the whole content. No arbitrary buffer that is guaranteed to hold the whole content is needed. The returned array is exactly as big as it needs to be. Only a small read buffer is used to increase performance. Error handling is ignored.

This assumes that the data is not larger than it fits into memory.

```
byte[] readFromDevice(UartDevice uartDevice) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int read;
    ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while ((read = uartDevice.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
        data.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    return data.toByteArray();
}
```

The method returns when all data has been read and you can process the returned array at your leasure.

Comment: I have to process the bytes further. And unless I receive the whole bytes in buffer I can go for processing the receiving bytes.

Comment: can I put some condition in this? For example, If I want it to keep writing till '\n' is that possible?